# Stop javascript automatically casting from decimal to string

Tags: javascript, casting

I have the following piece of code:

```
if(netAnnualBilling == null){
                        netAnnualBilling = 0;
                        parseFloat(netAnnualBilling);
                }
                parseFloat(netAnnualBilling);
                annualBillingCount = (annualBillingCount + netAnnualBilling);
                parseFloat(annualBillingCount);
```

My two variables netAnnualBilling and annualBillingCount are both of type numbers. However, when I get to this line:

```
            annualBillingCount = (annualBillingCount + netAnnualBilling);
```

javascript seems to turn annualBillingCount into type String and appends the two numbers together instead of adding or subtracting as its supposed to. Example:

```
annualBillingCount = 0; 
netAnnualBilling = -1403.30
The result of the above code will show annualBillingCount to be equal to : 0-1403.80
```

I've tried ParseFloat every time these variables pop up but I'm not having any luck. What's going on?

Comment: Hmm, are you certain both are numbers? If they truly are, the addition will produce a number, not a string. Try it in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parseFloat()` doesn't change the value, it returns the casted value.  You need:

```
netAnnualBilling = parseFloat(netAnnualBilling)
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was missing, setting the parseFloat to a variable.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to make sure the variables are used as numbers, you can simply prepend the unary plus operator:

```
annualBillingCount = +annualBillingCount + +netAnnualBilling;
```

will force each operand to be treated as a number.

**EDIT** [Heres a basic fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BLFZp/) showing the addition of two strings with varying uses of the unary casting, using the code below:

```
var onetwo = "12";
var threefour = "34";

alert(onetwo + threefour); // string + string, so "12" + "34" = "1234"
alert(+onetwo + threefour); // number + string, so 12 + "34" = "12" + "34" = "1234"
alert(onetwo + +threefour); // string + number, second will be coerced back to string, so "12" + "34" = "1234"
alert(+onetwo + +threefour); // number + number, so 12 + 34 = 46
```

Comment: This worked too. Unfortunately the IDE i'm using (Aptana) gives JsLint warnings when putting two + signs next to each other and I was unfortunately unable to use this. But great info for the future!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(netAnnualBilling == null) {
     netAnnualBilling = 0;
}
netAnnualBilling = parseFloat(netAnnualBilling);
annualBillingCount = parseFloat(annualBillingCount);
annualBillingCount += netAnnualBilling;
```